# Development of Saturn I

Tags: saturn-i

I have read that Saturn I was started to meet the special requirements of DoD. The question is: Are there any records available which clarify / spell out **WHY** " Department of Defense (DoD) needed a heavy-lift vehicle to orbit a new class of communications and "other" satellites, such as to call for a vehicle capable of putting 20,000 to 40,000 pounds (9,100 to 18,100 kg) into orbit ...."

Answer (score 2):

The article [Cluster's Last Stand](https://thehighfrontier.blog/2017/02/27/clusters-last-stand-the-saturn-i1b/) about Saturn 1 development states that the military's goals were

> orbiting large communications satellites, manned space stations and even developing the strangelove-esque atomic moon bases under Project Horizon.

[Project Horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Horizon)

> was a 1959 study to determine the feasibility of constructing a scientific / military base on the Moon, at a time when the U.S. Department of the Army, Department of the Navy, and Department of the Air Force had total responsibility for U.S. space program plans

Comment: I appreciate providing the links. On reading the same, I understand that V. Braun (@ABMA) worked upon the super Jupiter while overcoming the frustration of being sidelined on the missile issue by the DoD, and in Dec. 1957 proposed the big booster to ARPA, which was a fallout of Sputnik. Since Eisenhower was looking for an appropriate US response to the perceived Russian superiority in space, this new proposal was found attractive & pursued further by ARPA with their directive dated 15th Aug. 58. However this does not seem as being a "Military" ..  **see next comment**.

Comment: Contd... requirement per se, except that it was a part of Eisenhower's intended preparation of a response to Russia. The typical wording "heavy-lift vehicle to orbit a new class of communications and "other" satellites" somehow gives an impression of creating a big and clandestine WEAPON rather than a space exploration vehicle. IS MY UNDERSTANDING CORRECT???